# cannot implicity convert string to int

Tags: c#, string, int, converters

```
        TextBox1.Enabled = false;
        finalpricebox.Items.Clear();
        namebox.Items.Clear();
        int current = 0;
        pricebox.Items.Clear();
        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            request.Navigate("http:----------" + TextBox1.Text);
        }
        else if (CheckBox1.Checked == false)
        {
            request.Navigate("http://----" + TextBox1.Text);
        }
        namebox.Focus();
        while (!(request.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete))
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        WebClient tClient = new WebClient();

        int resultnr = request.Document.GetElementById("searchResults_total").OuterText;
        if (resultnr > 30)
        {
            resultnr = 30;
        }
```

it says that cannot implicity convert string to int. on the line

int resultnr = request.Document.GetElementById("searchResults_total").OuterText;
        if (resultnr > 30)

why do i get this error, i really hope someone can help me out

Comment: on which specific line?

Answer (score 0):

```
int resultnr = Convert.ToInt32(request.Document.GetElementById("searchResults_total").OuterText);
```

Comment: thank you for the fast answer :D

Comment: For future reference (for others who come across this post), can you please add some context and explanation as to what the code is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for safe side

```
  int resultnr =0;
  if(int.TryParse(request.Document.GetElementById("searchResults_total").OuterText,out resultnr )
   {
        if (resultnr > 30)
        {
            resultnr = 30;
        }
   }
```